# Django Error: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'

Tags: django, django-views

I am using Djagno 4.1.2. I successfully used the built in

```
Class Example(CreateView):
```

from

```
django.views.generic.edit
```

When I submitted the form I received an error because Django didn't know what to do next. I had forgotten to put in the

```
success_url
```

I imported

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

and my view looked like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from Techtips.models import Techtip
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class TechtipCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Techtip
    fields = ['title', 'year', 'year2', 'make', 'model', 'description']
    template_name = 'techtips/create_techtip.html',
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

The next time I tried to use this view I received the following error:

```
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/techtips/create/

Django Version: 4.1.2
Python Version: 3.10.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Techtips',
 'Home',
 'accounts',
 'phonenumber_field']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 90, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 72, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 175, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 157, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\cached.py", line 57, in get_template
    template = super().get_template(template_name, skip)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 17, in get_template
    for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\cached.py", line 70, in get_template_sources
    yield from loader.get_template_sources(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 35, in get_template_sources
    name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 143, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\Users\Logan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '

Exception Type: TypeError at /techtips/create/
Exception Value: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'
```

I removed the succes_url line and retried. Now I am getting this error every time I try to access url 'create' or '/techtips/create/'.

Here is the current (still receiving error):

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from Techtips.models import Techtip
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'techtips/index.html')


class TechtipCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Techtip
    fields = ['title', 'year', 'year2', 'make', 'model', 'description']
    template_name = 'techtips/create_techtip.html',
```

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from Techtips import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('create/', views.TechtipCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Techtip(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    make = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_revised = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I returned the code to what I believed was the original when things were working. I must be missing something because it was just a minor addition to the View.

Comment: remove the trailing comma of `template_name = 'techtips/create_techtip.html',`.

Comment: If I could kick myself harder I would. Thank you. That did the trick.